# Pass variable to CakePHP Helper inside the options array

Tags: php, cakephp, helper

This is setting a bread crumb but could be used on any helper i assume. I am trying to link to the current article that i am viewing in the bread crumb but not sure how to add the post ID after the view/ URL as i do with the news title before it?

```
$this->Html->addCrumb($news['News']['title'], array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'view/'$news['News']['id']));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean:

```
$this->Html->addCrumb(
    $news['News']['title'], array(
        'controller' => 'news', 
        'action' => 'view/' . $news['News']['id']
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer the CakePHP format to do it :)

```
$this->Html->addCrumb(
    $news['News']['title'], array(
        'controller' => 'news', 
        'action' => 'view',
         $news['News']['id']
    )
);
```